# OpenGL: Fetch depth on Tiled GPU with color-only fetch extension

Tags: android, opengl-es, arm, depth-buffer

I want to fetch depth from tile local memory with OpenGL ES.

That is needed to make soft particles effect and color-only deferred decals in a videogame.
[ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch_depth_stencil](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARM/ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch_depth_stencil.txt) extension works great and gives direct access to depth value.

Now I want to achieve same result with [ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARM/ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch.txt) and [EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch.txt).
In GDC talk [Bringing Fortnite to Mobile with Vulkan and OpenGL ES](https://youtu.be/XCUfk5vRblo?t=1625) I see that one possible solution is **writing depth value to alpha**.

This approach doesn't work for me because of major precision loss, my alpha is 8 bits only.
I consider adding second attachment with enough precision and writing to it with [MRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_Render_Targets).

**The question is**: is MRT a way to go, or I miss some important trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementations that support `ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch` do not guarantee to support MRT at all. If they do support it, then only the color of attachment zero can be retrieved. There are also some restrictions around color format; e.g. it only supports unorm color formats, so likely cannot have enough precision for depth even if you put the depth info in attachment zero.

Using `EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch` is more generic and adds full MRT support, but not all tile-based GPUs support it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I already noticed that `ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch` allows only fetching from attachment 0, but color format restriction info is super helpful. MRT with `EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch ` seems a way-to-go. I see also other option: `EXT_shader_pixel_local_storage`, but didn't investigate. Main question was about how ue4 achieve reasonable depth value in alpha channel, I think to answer this I need to capture some ue4 frames with graphics debugger. If I do - I will add info there.